# Proguard warning "Can't find referenced class packagename.R$string " with gradle 3.3.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard

Proguard fails with warning after updating gradle plugin to '3.3.2'.
The warning is :
"Can't find referenced class packagename.R$string "

it's working fine with gradle plugin '3.2+'

The issue might be because of(As per behavioural changes of 3.3) :

> Faster R class generation for library projects: Previously, the
>   Android Gradle plugin would generate an R.java file for each of your
>   project's dependencies and then compile those R classes alongside your
>   app's other classes. The plugin now generates a JAR containing your
>   app's compiled R class directly, without first building intermediate
>   R.java classes. This optimization may significantly improve build
>   performance for projects that include many library subprojects and
>   dependencies, and improve the indexing speed in Android Studio.

Comment: Have you checked [ProGuard manual](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/troubleshooting#unresolvedclass) for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

apply below codes to your `gradle.properties` file.

```
# Disables R8 for Android Library modules only.
android.enableR8.libraries = false

# Disables R8 for all modules.
android.enableR8 = false
```